# Solr performance very slow?

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.6 storing thousands of documents. By virtue of implementation, I can use only boolean queries to fetch documents from the index but it is very slow taking at least 20 seconds to get a result. I am using 4G of dedicated RAM for Solr.

Can anybody help me with performance optimization?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what queries are you using?

Comment: q=test&q.op=OR&df=text&qt=%2Fselect&sort=score+desc&content_source=Alfresco&content_source=SharePoint&alf_acls=GROUP_EVERYONE&alf_acls=GROUP_site_about-irish-water&alf_acls=GROUP_site_about-irish-water_SiteCollaborator&AuthenticatedUserName=ljangra

Comment: You are not talking to Solr directly, are you? This is some sort of Alfresco setup. You may want to focus on that layer first, as half of the parameters in the list make no sense to Solr itself.

Apart from that, I would do a very quick test to check what happens if you don't sort by description. That could be a contributing factor.

Comment: I am talking to solr directly. I have indexed alfresco & sharepoint content in solr along with ACLs for each content & storing them in solr. Here alf_acls means alfresco ACLs for a user. I am sorting by relevancy score here in descending order.

Comment: The point made by @AlexandreRafalovitch is that any part of the url after (and including) `&content_source` is ignored by Solr. How many documents are we talking? What is the index size? Are you querying from the Solr Admin interface?